# How to turn off “Shake to show Change Keyboard window” on Nexus 5?

Tags: nexus-5

Every time I shake my Nexus 5, the Change Keyboard window pops-up.

[image]

Please let me know how to turn it off. The Andriod version in my phone is `6.0.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, recently I installed ICICI app on my phone. Along with this app a keyboard called 'ICICI Smartkeys' got installed which has updated the default behavior for shake gesture on my phone to pop-up 'Change Keyboard' window. Disabling the keyboard fixed the issue.

Comment: ICICI iMobile app is the culprit!

Comment: ...and how do we disable that keyboard?

Comment: Settings --> lanugages and inputs-->virtual keyboard-->manage keyboards--> select and disable

Comment: The same thing is observed with my Moto X Play, I think all the devices that have ICICI's iMobile app install has the same issue. Nice observation @sajal. The solution worked for me.